# Setting VM Notes in VMware via Terraform

Tags: vmware-vsphere, terraform

We've started using Hashicorp Terraform to manage provisioning in our VMware environment but we're having difficulty modifying the Notes for a VM. It seems we need to use the custom_configuration_parameters in the terraform plan but it's not clear what key we need to use. Anyone happen to know what the appropriate key is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be a bit confusing, since Notes exists under Annotations, together with other custom attribues. But I found that just setting:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  ..
  annotation = "Deploy via Terraform"
 ..
}
```

will give you the text in the Notes field.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/r/virtual_machine.html#annotation